# XML to PHP variables

Tags: php, xml, variables, xml-parsing

I have a problem with my xml-php-script.
XML doc: http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Stockholm/Stockholm/forecast.xml

```
$xmlstr = "http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Stockholm/Stockholm/forecast.xml";

//$vader = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$vader = simplexml_load_file($xmlstr);

foreach ($vader->forecast->tabular->time->temperature as $temp) {
   echo $temp->temperature, ' ', $temp->windSpeed, PHP_EOL;
}
```

I want temperature in a variable named: `$temp`

Comment: Hi, thanks

I add weatherdata, but still not work.

url: http://soldagar.se/ajja.php

Comment: No you should not add `weatherdata` because that is the root node. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple `<time>`s, so you can loop those. Also, the `temperature` and `windSpeed` are in attributes.

```
foreach ($vader->forecast->tabular->time as $time) {
   echo $time->temperature->attributes()->value, ' ', $time->windSpeed->attributes()->mps, PHP_EOL;

   // or store temperature in a variable?
   // $temp = $time->temperature;
   // echo $temp->attributes()->value; // 14
   // echo $temp->attributes()->unit; // celcius
}
```

Or to access just the first `<time>`:

```
echo $vader->forecast->tabular->time[0]->temperature->attributes()->value;
echo $vader->forecast->tabular->time[0]->windSpeed->attributes()->mps;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting output

echo $temp->temperature, ' ', $temp->windSpeed, PHP_EOL;

from this then you can get tenperature values as below

PHP Code :

```
    $temp_array = array();
    $tempt_str = ''
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($vader->forecast->tabular->time->temperature as $temp) {
       $tempt_str .= 'temperature : '.$temp->temperature.''.'windSpeed : '.$temp->windSpeed.'<br/>';
       $temp_array[$i]['temperature'] = $temp->temperature;
       $temp_array[$i]['windSpeed'] = $temp->windSpeed;
    }
```